# What is the uses of numbers other than counting things?

Tags: math-history

When I think for example of the numbers 1 or 2 or 3, I would immediately visualize in my head that I have 1 item or 2 items or 3 items (so I immediately associate numbers with counting things).

But are numbers only used for counting things, or does numbers have other uses too?

Comment: Measuring, moving, rotating, transforming, communicating, ...

Comment: This will be better answersed in HSM (History of Science and Mathematics) StackExchange.

Comment: There are 3 common types of number in daily usages. cardinal (size of something), ordinal (rank or order of items in a set) and norminal (name or identify something, doesn't represent any quantity)

Comment: Maybe useful Leo Corry, [A Brief History of Numbers (Oxford University Press, 2015)](https://books.google.it/books?id=BQI7CgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) as well as Karl Menninger, [Number Words and Number Symbols: A Cultural History of Numbers (1958)](https://books.google.it/books?id=RXbCAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to expand off of achille hui's comment, as I think it is highly agreeable among mathematics; it sums up nicely into three groups.

## [Cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number)

Probably the first type of quantity we think of when referring to numbers are cardinals. When a number is a cardinal, it generally means it's denoting an *amount*. I.e; in the sentence:

> I have 5 apples

5 is a cardinal. Cardinals are usually the type of numbers in counting, but "counting" can also be applied to the next type of numbers.

## [Ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number)

Just as common as cardinals, are the ordinals. Name implied, they're used for denoting order / placement. In the sentence:

> I finished in 5'th place

5 is an ordinal. Notice how a 'place' doesn't have an 'amount', but it does have an order. Counting can come up here too. E.g;

> I know I finished in 5'th place because I counted 4 people that finished before me.

Here, 5 is still an ordinal but 4 is a cardinal - so cardinals and ordinals can be very much intertwined.

## [Nominals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_number)

Last but not least, we use nominals when we don't care about quantity or order. They're used as labels to distinguish separate things. In the sentence:

> The first digit in my phone number is 5

5 is a nominal. This is because phone numbers don't necessarily have a quantity nor an order, but they are unique - so we use a unique series of numbers as a label to distinguish between phones.